# Add parameters for padding a string (C#)

Tags: c#, string-formatting

`{0,N}` formatting pads a string to the left with spaces. For example:

```
string [] names = { "A", "Bob", "Charles" };
Console.WriteLine("{0}{0,15}", names[0]);
Console.WriteLine("{0}{0,13}", names[1]);
Console.WriteLine("{0}{0,10}", names[2]);
```

Which results in lines with a total length of 16 characters:

```
A                A
Bob            Bob
Charles    Charles
```

You can achieve the same thing with `String.PadLeft`, for example:

```
foreach (var name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", name, name.PadLeft(16-name.Length, ' '));
}
```

This attempt to add a parameter to `{0,N}` formatting compiles, but throws an exception at runtime:

```
foreach (var name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{0,16-name.Length}", name);
}
```

Is it possible to pass a parameter into `{0,N}` style formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) and double the braces for the format pattern:

```
string[] names = { "A", "Bob", "Charles" };

int paddingMax = 16;

foreach (string name in names)
  Console.WriteLine($"{{0}}{{0,{paddingMax - name.Length}}}", name);
```

Output:

```
A              A
Bob          Bob
Charles  Charles
```

To check for outbreaks:

```
foreach ( string name in names )
{
  int padding = paddingMax - name.Length;
  if ( padding < 0 )
    Console.WriteLine("Padding error for: " + name);
  else
    Console.WriteLine($"{{0}}{{0,{padding}}}", name);
```